# Geometric Brownian Motion w/ Normal Distribution

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

> Problem and Answer:
>
> $$\mathbb{E} [X_t] = \int^\infty_{-\infty} e^{\mu t + \sigma x}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2t}}dx= e^{\mu t + t\frac{\sigma^2}{2}}$$

I don't understand the middle steps to get to the answer. I get that $ut$ is constant, and you bring $\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}\right)$ in front of the integral, but I'm not understanding what I should do after that.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral#The_integral_of_a_Gaussian_function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$I = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{\mu t+\sigma x} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2t}}dx = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}} e^{\mu t} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{\sigma x -\frac{x^2}{2t}}dx$$
We now need to complete the square of the exponent,  $$\sigma x -\frac{x^2}{2t} = -\frac{1}{2t}(x^2-2t\sigma x) = -\frac{1}{2t}(x^2-2t\sigma x + (t\sigma)^2) + \frac{(t\sigma)^2}{2t} = -\frac{1}{2t}(x - t\sigma)^2 + \frac{1}{2}t\sigma^2$$
Now, let $u= x-t\sigma$ and $du = dx$.

$$I = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}} e^{\mu t + \frac{1}{2}t\sigma^2} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac{1}{2t}u^2}dx = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}} e^{\mu t + \frac{1}{2}t\sigma^2} \sqrt{2\pi t} = e^{\mu t + \frac{1}{2}t\sigma^2}$$

Note that I used the fact that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-ax^2} = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}$

Comment: Where did the (tσ)^2 come from when you were completing the square?

Comment: I add it him. To complete the square, we want something of the form $x^2-2ax+a^2$ so that we can factor it like this $(x-a)^2$. Note that the $a^2$ part is "missing" and in our case is $(t\sigma^2)$. That why I also add $\frac{(t\sigma)^2}{2t}$ so that they cancel out.

Comment: I misted type, it should be $(t\sigma)^2$ and not $(t\sigma^2)$ in the above comment.